# Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Id, Set<Id> at line 20 column 21

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I have the error in the title please help me. this is my code

```
 public class sample_class{


 public void CannotDelete(List<Account> angelacode){  
 Set<ID> acc_id = new Set<ID>();
 Set<ID> cont_id = new Set<ID>();
 List<Account> account_qry = new List<Account>();
 List<Contact> contact_qry = new List<Contact>();

for (Account acct : angelacode){
   contact_qry = [Select AccountId,AssistantName,Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN : acc_Id];
       for (Contact cont : contact_qry){
           if (cont.AccountId != 'NULL'){
           cont_id.add(cont.AccountId);
           }
           }
           for (Account account : angelacode){
             if(account.id == cont_id){
             acct.addError('CannotDelete');
             }


           }

   }


}
```

}

Comment: `if(account.id == cont_id){` => `if(cont_id.contains(account.id)){`

Answer (score 2):

See Martin's comment for the specific syntax problem.

When coding Apex, care needs to be taken to avoid hitting governor limits. Your code is doing a query inside a loop which opens the danger of exceeding the maximum number of queries governor limit (presently 100). Also looping over one list and inside that loop looping over another list to find a matching value makes the execution time increase exponentially (much faster than in proportion to the number of items) - better to use maps keyed by ID values.

Your current code looks like it aims to add an error to one of the input accounts if there are any related contacts. Code for that which avoids the two problems would look something like this:

```
public class sample_class{

    public void CannotDelete(List<Account> angelacode) {
        for (Account a : [
                select Id, (select Id from Contacts)
                from Account
                where Id in :angelacode
                ]) {
            if (a.Contacts.size() > 0) {
                a.addError('CannotDelete');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and makes use of [relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) rather than hand coded loops and ID matches.

Comment: though I want to ask what is (select Id from Contacts) for?

Comment: There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger CannotDelete caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CannotDelete: execution of BeforeDelete caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors: Class.sample_class.CannotDelete: line 10, column 1".

though it does not delete when it has account, it has this unexpected exception error. how to solve this?

Comment: @gelay The Id value isn't used but for the query to be valid something has to be there (and every object has an Id). Only the size of the Contacts list is used in the logic.

Comment: @gelay The error in your comment relates to the type of trigger you are calling this code from. Suggest you post the trigger and class in a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: what if I want to use something like 
account_qry = [Select Id from Account Where Id in : angelacode]
will this work?

Comment: @gelay That query is valid but will just give you the same set of accounts.

Comment: When I use that It still can delete accounts with contacts

Comment: what should be my qry if that will be my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Like @martin mentioned in the comment, to see if a Set has a value you need to use the contains method. From the help docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_methods_system_set):

> **contains(setElement)**
>
> Returns true if the set contains the specified element.
>
> **Signature**
>
> public Boolean contains(Object setElement)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> setElement
>
> Type: Object
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Set<String> myString = new Set<String>{'a', 'b'};
> Boolean result = myString.contains('z');
> System.assertEquals(false, result);
> ```

A couple other things I noticed in your code:
1. You are looping through the accounts that are sent in and inside that loop you are querying for the related contacts, you risk hitting governor limits and should never have a query inside of a for loop.
2. Your query is being filtered by the acc_id set, but there are no values assigned to this set - assuming that this class is called by a trigger you could pass in the map vs the list and use the map keyset to filter your query.

There is a great module on trailhead for triggers [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_triggers). There is also a workbook that walks you through a similar example of preventing deletion of invoices with invoice line items [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/).